# Ruby on rails routing error following tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am following [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), 4.3 Setting the Application Home Page. The end results are meant to direct the localhost page to `/welcome/index`. When I go to localhost, it does not redirect me. The console gives this message:

> started GET "/assests/rails.png" for....
>   .... served asset /rails.png - 304 not modified (1ms)

The message the console gives is a good thing, and not the cause of my problem. Why am I not being redirected?

Comment: We cannot see what you have done, so we cannot begin to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remove `index.html` from `public/` directory?

Comment: Thank-you very much, I dont think the tutorial said anything about this, but it has worked and the redirect is working now. THanks for helping a newbie!